# upper bound the number of 5-cycles in a random graph

Tags: combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

Let $k$ be the number of edges of a graph $G$, I’d want to show that $G$ can contain at most $(2k)^\frac{5}{2}$ cycles of length $5$.

I thought about showing this for the Erdös-Renyi graph model $G(2k,k)$ where $2k$ is the amount of nodes.

Now ideally I’d show that $P(\#5 $-cycles $ $ in $G > (2k)^\frac{5}{2})=0$ where G is a realisation of $G(2k,k)$

However, when considering the expression $(2k)^\frac{5}{2}$, the exponent puzzles me. I see no straightforward way to get the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the exponent like say by using markov’s inequality or so, whereas $2k$ shows up naturally by the fact that one can choose both a direction and a starting node for a cycle.

Any ideas on how to further this direction or another way to show this?

Comment: If you want to prove that something is true for *all* graphs, it is not useful to look at random graphs; you will not find probabilistic tools to help you show that the probability your statement is false is $0$. The probabilistic method is useful for the opposite problem: if you want to prove that a graph with a certain property *does* exist, then you can try to show that the probability that a random graph has the property is positive.